# Apache gzip + кеширование

Tags: apache, gzip

Как настроить gzip на Apache так, чтобы статические файлы (например, js) один раз сжавшись, кешировались и раздавались из кэша.

Answer (score 1):

Кеш - имеете ввиду `mod_cache`? Например:

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>    CacheLock on    CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock    CacheLockMaxAge 5</IfModule>
```

С gzip примерно так же. Или может что-то из этого не получается?

Вот что имеется в онлай документации тут используется mod_deflate, на сколько я понил gzip тут не причем

```
<Location />SetOutputFilter DEFLATEBrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/htmlBrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzipBrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html# Don't compress imagesSetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-varyHeader append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary</Location>
```

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть это на примере. Главное, чего хочется избежать - не сжимать файлы самому, а пусть это делается автоматически.Судя по документации, у mod_gzip есть опция mod_gzip_can_negotiate, которая говорит о том, что если например, есть файл interface.js.gz, то вернуть его вместо interface.jsНо чтобы это все работало, необходимо самому подготовить эти файлы gz. Может есть какое решение, которое бы жало и кэшировало статические файлы одновременно?

Comment: apache  на юнихе?